# Hourly screenshot taker

Tags: windows, automation, screenshot

I'd like to take a screenshot on an hourly basis (with an option for as short as minutely, or long as daily would be nice).

And automatically delete previous day's/week's screenshots. It'd be nice if I could actually choose between the two (daily vs weekly) but if not that's fine too. 
Or it should delete based on the folder size, i.e. delete oldest screenshots if overall folder size exceeds XX amount. Just any one of the "automatic deletion" methods would be fine.

It should save in a local folder.

Screenshot should be of entire screen. Although not necessary but if it lets me mask or crop a certain area that'd be nice too.

Also it be nice if it had the ability to sleep (not take screenshots) when there's no user activity (time since last mouse movement >~ XX sec)

Is there any such software that does this?

OS: Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Ardamax Keylogger](http://www.ardamax.com/keylogger/):

- non-free
- Windows
- capture screenshots at regular intervals and can be configured not to capture screenshots when the system is idle:

[image]

- can specify the maximum log file:

[image]

Comment: It saves screenshots in its own logging file format which you can only view through its own viewer. Other than that it's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: What about the ability to delete past screenshots?

Comment: I've found that it ***can*** save screenshots in a folder. [You just need to "deliver" it via "network path" to any local folder](http://i.imgur.com/wLqMs2Z.png).

Comment: @Gilles Good point, added in the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [timesnapper classic](http://www.timesnapper.com/DownloadClassic.aspx) at work, it works really great

It's free, easy to configure

[image: Timesnapper]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. We want answers that explain how the recommended product matches the requirements and fits the purpose of the question. See [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356) for tips on writing an answer. What about the ability to delete past screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

[IcyScreen](http://www.16software.com/icyscreen/)

IcyScreen is an automatic screenshot taker / automatic screen capture program that can automatically save screenshots to disk, upload them to a web server via FTP, and e-mail them to an unlimited number of recipients, including yourself.

[image]