# Create ASCII art tables

Tags: table, ascii

## Create ASCII art tables

Required:

- Merged cells (horizontally, vertically, both)
- Centering (horizontally, vertically, both)
- Free as in beer
- Easy input

Nice to have:

- Arbitrary alignment (horizontally, vertically, both)
- Automated row numbering
- Automated sorting
- Platform: Cloud/Web (on stable, reliable host), Google Sheets, VS Code, Sublime Text or Excel
- FLOSS + public repository + actively developed + taking feature requests + accepting contributions

---

**Example** table: [Windows Tool for automatic regular screenshots](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/43497/windows-tool-for-automatic-regular-screenshots)
[image]

Simple version inline:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|    |                     |           A           |       B       |       C       |
+ Nr +         Name        +-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|    |                     | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+----+---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1 | Very very long name |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+----+---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  2 | Short name          |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+----+---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 5):

[Plain Text Table](https://github.com/PlainTextTools/plain-text-table) suits most of your requirements. It's free and open sourced

> ### Use the tool online
>
> Please visit : http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table
>
> ### Features
>
> - Interactive input table (using [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/))
> - Unicode or ASCII output
> - Flexible border configuration
> - Merged cell support (colspan and rowspan)
> - Multiline text in the cells
> - Text alignement support (horizontal and vertical)
> - Predefined style
>
> All configuration options explained in the [user manual](https://github.com/PlainTextTools/plain-text-table/blob/gh-pages/user_manual/README.md).

It also supports automatic numbering

[image: example]